# Plot filtered patch sizes in R terra

Tags: r, terra

I would like to plot patch sizes above a threshold in R terra.

```
f=system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r=rast(f)
x=app(r,function(x) ifelse(x< 400,NA,x))
y=patches(x)
z=tapply(cellSize(y,unit="ha")[], y[], sum)
filtered=z[z>100]
```

The "filtered" variable contains patches larger than 100 ha. How do I plot them in terra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(terra)
f = system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r = rast(f)
x = classify(r, cbind(-Inf, 400, NA))
y = patches(x)
```

Instead of `tapply` you can use `zonal` (and also notice the use of `classify` instead of `app` above)

```
z = cellSize(y,unit="ha") |> zonal(y, sum)
head(z)
#  patches        area
#1       1 47932.88521
#2       2   166.04838
#3       3    55.37478
#4       4   387.87970
#5       5    55.41274
#6       6    55.46017
```

By setting `as.raster=TRUE` you get these values on the raster

```
rz = zonal(cellSize(y,unit="ha"), y, sum, as.raster=TRUE)
rz
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : memory 
#name        :     area 
#min value   : 55.37478 
#max value   : 47932.89
```

And now you can remove the small patches

```
s = ifel(rz < 100, NA, 1)
# or, if you want to keep the patch numbers
s = ifel(rz < 100, NA, y)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `filtered` variable is a table of patch numbers and areas. The `names` of the table are the patch numbers.

To plot a map of TRUE/FALSE for those patches, do a boolean (logical) operator to see which values of `y` are in that set:

```
plot(y %in% as.numeric(names(filtered)))
```

[image]

or if you want a raster with those patches and their patch values (first I've made a copy so I don't stomp on `y`), set all that *arent* in the set to `NA`:

```
yf = y
yf[!yf %in% as.numeric(names(filtered))] = NA
plot(yf)
```

[image]